# Axois request value from querystring

Tags: reactjs, axios

How do I get the value from query string and pass it to Axios? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Here is what I have.  Thank

```
http://localhost:3000/article/id/5ff15120a012a42238acdcd6


 useEffect(async() => {       
        const response = await Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL + '/api/article/id',{params:???}, {withCredentials:true})
        setArtclelData(response.data) 
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer already. Here is the code:

```
import {useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const {id} = useParams()

useEffect(async() => {       
        const response = await Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL + `/api/article/id/${id}`, {withCredentials:true})
        setArtclelData(response.data) 
    }, [])
```